# Firefox Developer Tools - Can't Show Nodes In Inspector

Tags: firefox, debugger, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to move from Chrome Dev Tools to Firefox (27.0.1) for day-to-day debugging, however I keep hitting a problem in the inspector that can only be fixed by restarting Firefox.

The first time I load a page I get full access to the DOM, however on subsequent loads/refreshes I get this in the Inspector window:

[image]

Clicking the 'Show all 307 Nodes' button has no effect. Clicking On the collapse node button also has no effect. My Rules/Computed/Fonts/Box Model panels are all empty.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: whats your firefox version?

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 27.0.1 (Added to Q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are bumping into [bug 950732](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=950732).  This was fixed in Firefox 29, which you can get by downloading [Aurora](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/).

There are a lot of [new features](https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/developer-tools/) and bug fixes (like this) for web developers that are landing with the latest browser versions, and by using Aurora you can get a chance to use them earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The node inspect button in the devtools has moved from the inspector-panel toolbar, on the left, to the toolbox toolbar, on the right:

new node highlighter position in the devtools

The highlighter is shown as you hover over nodes in the markup-panel (instead of having to click on them)

[image]